# multi parameters in SQL for DB2, using SSRS

Tags: sql, db2, ssrs-2008, peoplesoft

I am very very new to SSRS for Sql Server. Using 2008. My work has asked me to reproduce some legacy reports using this tool -- and I got as far as creating the drop-downs for my parameters and ran into the error that multi parameters were not supported by DB2. We use PeopleSoft tables. My work has now said, find a workaround. I have been reading many forums and I just cannot get anything off the ground. Can anyone provide a resource or walk me through what I'd need to do to force this report to allow my users to select multiple parameters?

```
SELECT AL1.EMPLID, AL1.NAME,
       AL4.COVERAGE_ELECT, AL4.FLAT_AMOUNT,
       AL1.JOBTITLE, AL1.JOB_FAMILY,
       AL3.ANNUAL_RT, AL3.ANNL_BENEF_BASE_RT,
       AL4.BENEFIT_PLAN
FROM TABLEONE AL1,
     TABLETWO AL2,
     TABLETHREE AL3,
     TABLEFOUR AL4
WHERE (AL1.EMPLID = AL3.EMPLID
       AND AL1.EMPL_RCD = AL3.EMPL_RCD
       AND AL1.EMPLID = AL2.EMPLID
       AND AL1.EMPL_RCD = AL2.EMPL_RCD
       AND AL1.EMPLID = AL4.EMPLID
       AND AL1.EMPL_RCD = AL4.EMPL_RCD)
       AND (AL2.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(LF.effdt)
                         FROM TABLETWO LF
                         WHERE LF.emplid = al2.emplid
                               AND LF.empl_rcd = al2.empl_rcd
                               AND LF.plan_type = al2.plan_type
                               AND LF.benefit_nbr = al2.benefit_nbr
                               AND LF.effdt <= CURRENT Date)
            AND AL2.PLAN_TYPE = '20'
            AND AL2.COVERAGE_ELECT = 'E'
            AND AL3.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(J.EFFDT)
                             FROM TABLETHREE J
                             WHERE J.EMPLID = AL3.EMPLID
                                   AND J.EMPL_RCD = AL3.EMPL_RCD
                                   AND J.EFFDT <= CURRENT Date)
            AND AL3.EFFSEQ = (SELECT MAX(ES.EFFSEQ)
                              FROM TABLETHREE ES
                              WHERE ES.EMPLID = AL3.EMPLID
                                    AND ES.EMPL_RCD = AL3.EMPL_RCD
                                    AND ES.EFFDT = AL3.EFFDT)
            AND AL4.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(L.EFFDT)
                             FROM TABLETWO L
                             WHERE L.EMPLID = AL4.EMPLID
                                   AND L.EMPL_RCD = AL4.EMPL_RCD
                                   AND L.PLAN_TYPE = AL4.PLAN_TYPE
                                   AND L.BENEFIT_NBR = AL4.BENEFIT_NBR
                                   AND L.EFFDT <= CURRENT Date)
            AND AL4.PLAN_TYPE IN (?)
            AND AL4.COVERAGE_ELECT= ?)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link on how to get a workaround, using multiple parameters, if doesn't helps you post a bit more on what you did and we will find an answer, I worked on similar issue a few weeks earlier. Here is the link: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/MS-SQL_Reporting/A_8737-SSRS-can-be-also-used-for-user-inputs.html

Basically what I did: 1. I connected to a dataSource. Then I set Up my DataSet. In the dataset you can enter the select statement you provided, or if you are using a stored procedure you can opt to choose that option as well. 
In VS there is a folder named Parameters. You can add both your parameters there. Set it to visible. I allowed null values and blank values in case the user selects nothing. I specified values for my dropdown. And thats all on the creation side.
Now you can go back to your data set and add a line:

```
WHERE column = + @DropdownParameter +
AND column2 = +@Dropdown2Parameter +
```

I am just writing the part of the code you were interested. I didn't tested it, but this is similar to the way I did it in my project and there it works.

```
FROM TABLETWO
        WHERE PLAN_TYPE = +@DropdownParameter+
              AND EFFDT <= CURRENT_DATE
        GROUP BY EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, BENEFIT_NBR, PLAN_TYPE) INC
    ON T4.EMPLID = INC.EMPLID
       AND T4.EMPL_RCD = INC.EMPLRCD
       AND T4.BENEFIT_NBR = INC.BENEFIT_NBR
       AND T4.PLAN_TYPE = INC.PLAN_TYPE
       AND T4.EFFDT = INC.EFFDT
  WHERE T4.COVERAGE_ELECT = +@DropdownParameter2+) AL4
ON AL4.EMPLID = AL1.EMPLID
 AND AL4.EMPL_RCD = AL1.EMPL_RCD
```

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, i am NEW to this. Coming from Hyperion Intelligence Explorer which is a whole other animal. This is just for POC so we installed SSRS 2008 / Visual Studio and I created a test report. I added in some SQL (I'll have to put in a another comment due to comment length) to hit our DB2 tables and using only ONE fill in parameter, it worked fine. Once I supplied default parameters, error-town. Everything I'm reading just says "Oh, create a custom join or function for your parameters" but I'm afraid I'm not grasping it.

Comment: Ok, but to understand the question I would like to know something. You only need to present the data that is retrieved from a database, you don't need to execute any other operation do you?

Comment: Ok, I will try to provide the answer, but want to know a last thing. Your dropdown should do what. Let's say you have selected some value in one dropdown, and another value in the second dropdown, how should this affect the selection? could you give an example on this. Until then I will edit my answer and show you how I did it.

Comment: The value should bring back the query results for that parameter set only, much as it would if you manually replaced the values in your IN statement.

Answer (score 1):

... Wow, that's some query.  This isn't related to your problem, but the query should be cleaned up itself.  Among other things, please always explicitly specify your joins, don't use the comma-separated `FROM` clause.

This *may* work slightly better:

```
SELECT AL1.EMPLID, AL1.NAME,
       AL4.COVERAGE_ELECT, AL4.FLAT_AMOUNT,
       AL1.JOBTITLE, AL1.JOB_FAMILY,
       AL3.ANNUAL_RT, AL3.ANNL_BENEF_BASE_RT,
       AL4.BENEFIT_PLAN
FROM TABLEONE AL1,
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT EMPLID, EMPL_RCD
      FROM TABLETWO 
      WHERE PLAN_TYPE = '20'
            AND COVERAGE_ELECT = 'E'
            AND EFFDT <= CURRENT_DATE) AL2
  ON AL2.EMPLID = AL1.EMPLID
     AND AL2.EMPL_RCD = AL1.EMPL_RCD
JOIN (SELECT T3.EMPLID, T3.EMPL_RCD, T3.ANNUAL_RT, T3.ANNL_BENEF_BASE_RT
      FROM TABLETHREE T3
      JOIN (SELECT a.EMPLID, a.EMPL_RCD, a.EFFDT, MAX(EFFSEQ) EFFSEQ
            FROM (SELECT EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, MAX(EFFDT) EFFDT
                  FROM TABLETHREE 
                  GROUP BY EMPLID, EMPL_RCD) a
            JOIN TABLETHREE z
              ON z.EMPLID = a.EMPID
                 AND z.EMPL_RCD = a.EMPL_RCD
                 AND z.EFFDT = a.EFFDT
            GROUP BY a.EMPLID, a.EMPL_RCD, a.EFFDT) INC
        ON INC.EMPLID = T3.EMPLID
           AND INC.EMPL_RCD = T3.EMPL_RCD
           AND INC.EFFDT = T3.EFFDT
           AND INC.EFFSEQ = T3.EFFSEQ) AL3
  ON AL3.EMPLID = AL.EMPLID
     AND AL3.EMPL_RCD = AL1.EMPL_RCD
JOIN (SELECT T4.EMPLID, T4.EMPL_RCD, 
             T4.COVERAGE_ELECT, T4.FLAT_AMOUNT, T4.BENEFIT_PLAN
      FROM TABLEFOUR T4
      JOIN (SELECT EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, BENEFIT_NBR, PLAN_TYPE, MAX(EFFDT) EFFDT
            FROM TABLETWO
            WHERE PLAN_TYPE IN (?)
                  AND EFFDT <= CURRENT_DATE
            GROUP BY EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, BENEFIT_NBR, PLAN_TYPE) INC
        ON T4.EMPLID = INC.EMPLID
           AND T4.EMPL_RCD = INC.EMPLRCD
           AND T4.BENEFIT_NBR = INC.BENEFIT_NBR
           AND T4.PLAN_TYPE = INC.PLAN_TYPE
           AND T4.EFFDT = INC.EFFDT
      WHERE T4.COVERAGE_ELECT = ?) AL4
  ON AL4.EMPLID = AL1.EMPLID
     AND AL4.EMPL_RCD = AL1.EMPL_RCD
```

(Untested - without knowing your data layout it's somewhat difficult.  If there was more information available, it may be possible to simplify things still farther; notably if `TABLETHREE.EFFSEQ` is always increasing, or at least per `EFFDT`, that section can be collapsed to one reference)

Comment: +1... good code, but i can't see where did you add the part to select according to parameter? It looks better with the joins, good job

Comment: @Farkiba - I wasn't able to change that, and unfortunately I don't know anything about SSRS.  The only option may be to do dynamic SQL for the `IN` clause (the `COVERAGE_ELECT` can be a regular parameter marker, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple question marks for all your parameters. Make sure to match each of the question marks to a parameter, match them in the correct order. Like a few other legacy DBs (e.g. Ingres DB), IBM DB2 does not support named parameter in the query, therefore, use [?] for all your parameters. The rest steps are the same with your other reports design.

I think it also depends on which driver you are using for your report. This is the driver I am using for my DB2 reports. It comes from TOAD Analyse from Quest Inc.

IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - TACOM27

This is your query:

select * from tableA

where field1 = ?

and field2 = ?

These are your Parameters:

? = [@para1]

? = [@para2]