# Issue with dataset Creation

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I am new to ssrs and having difficulty defining parameters. I am trying to develop a code which will determine the parameters based on report type value 1 or 2.

I tried defining the parameters at run time using variables but no luck

```
SELECT  A.PRV_TIN_NO,
           B.CLM_PD_DT,
           A.CLM_FROM_DOS_DT,
           a.CLM_THRU_DOS_DT,
           A.GRP_NO 
    FROM CBDW.CBDW_CLM_MEDCL_HDR A
    INNER JOIN CBDW.CBDW_CLM_MEDCL_HDRLN B 
     ON A.GRP_NO = B.GRP_NO     
   WHERE (
    (@reporttype=1
      AND A.GRP_NO = @grpNo
      AND b.CLM_PD_DT >= @PaidfromDate
         AND b.CLM_PD_DT <=@PaidToDate
     )
OR 
          (@Reporttype=2
             AND A.GRP_NO = @grpNo
              AND a.CLM_FROM_DOS_DT>=@fromDate
              AND a.CLM_THRU_DOS_DT <=@ToDate
              AND b.CLM_PD_DT <=@PaidToDate
                   )
)
```

I am expecting to ssrs to prompt report type and when I select 1 parameters should be groupnumber and claim paid start date and end date while in option 2 I should also have service date parameter/

Comment: If you copied your SQL code, the second mention of `Reporttype` doesn't have an `@` in front of it to indicate it is a parameter.

Comment: I added and still throws error " Could not create a list of fields for the query. Verify that I can connect to data source and query syntax Is correct" ERROR [42S22] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0206N  "@REPORTTYPE" is not valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703

Comment: It looks like you're connecting to an IBM DB2 database - that's kinda important. For the query you'll need to use `?` instead of `@Reporttype` as well as for your other parameters. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638548/multi-parameters-in-sql-for-db2-using-ssrs

Comment: @HannoverFist Did you mean something like this?


  SELECT  A.PRV_TIN_NO,
           B.CLM_PD_DT,
           A.CLM_FROM_DOS_DT,
           a.CLM_THRU_DOS_DT,
           A.GRP_NO 
    FROM CBDW.CBDW_CLM_MEDCL_HDR A
    INNER JOIN CBDW.CBDW_CLM_MEDCL_HDRLN B 
     ON A.GRP_NO = B.GRP_NO     
   WHERE (
 (?=1
     AND A.GRP_NO = ?
      AND b.CLM_PD_DT >=?
      AND b.CLM_PD_DT <=?
     )
OR 
 (?=2
           AND A.GRP_NO = ?
           AND a.CLM_FROM_DOS_DT>=?
           AND a.CLM_THRU_DOS_DT <=?
           AND b.CLM_PD_DT <=?
                   )
)

Comment: @Robin - yes. Now you just have to map all of them from the Parameters tab of the dataset (ugh).